# Flattening a Binary Tree to a Linked List

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list, binary-tree

Hello I'm currently trying to solve this problem (unfortunately, there's no solution) :

http://blog.gainlo.co/index.php/2016/06/12/flatten-a-linked-list/

Basically, you want to flatten a linked list that has **next** pointer and **down** pointer to a singly linked list.

Below is what I've come up with, please correct me if there's anything wrong or if you find any edge cases that will break this.

```
static class Node {
    Node next;
    Node down;
    int val;
    Node(int val) {
        this.val = val;
    }
}

static Node flattenLinkedList(Node head) {
    Queue<Node> q = new LinkedList<>();
    q.add(head);
    Node dummyhead = new Node(0);
    Node pre = dummyhead;
    while (!q.isEmpty()) {
        Node current = q.poll();
        while (current != null) {
            pre.next = new Node(current.val);
            pre = pre.next;
            if (current.down != null) {
                q.add(current.down);
            }
            current = current.next;
        }
    }
    return dummyhead.next;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Node start = new Node(1);
    start.next = new Node(2);
    start.next.next = new Node(3);
    start.next.next.next = new Node(4);
    start.next.down = new Node(5);
    start.next.down.down = new Node(8);
    start.next.down.next = new Node(6);
    start.next.next.next.down = new Node(7);

    Node sol = flattenLinkedList(start);
}
```

P.S I'm doing this to practice for interviews, not for homework.

Comment: Have you written unit tests yourself?

Comment: @cricket_007, yep think it works for the example on the website but wanted to make sure if it's generally correct.

Comment: What do you mean you *think* it works? How did you verify?

Comment: Can you show your current unit tests?

Comment: @cricket_007 basically I recreated the example on the website. I will edit the code and add unit tests.

Comment: "A linked list that has next pointer and down pointer"--isn't that called a _binary tree_?

Comment: Agree with @ajb, what's being flattened here isn't a linked list at all, but a binary tree.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static Node flatten(Node n) {
    if (n==null) return n;

    Node p = n;

    while (p!=null) {
        if (p.down != null)  {
            Node pn = p.next;
            p.next = flatten(p.down);
            while (p.next!=null) {
                p = p.next;
            }
            p.next = pn;
        }
        p = p.next;
    }

    return n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your approach right, your function will flatten a tree layer by layer. Considering the following structure

```
1 --- 2 --- 3 ---------------- 4
      |     |
      21    31 --- 32 --- 33 
      |             |
      221          332
                   3332 - 3333
```

your function will return `1 2 3 4 21 31 32 33 221 332 3332 3333`.

Regarding drawbacks - I would notice creating new nodes in the loop and keeping the `dummyhead`. You could simplify your function to

```
static void flatten(Node n) {
    Queue<Node> q = new LinkedList<>();
    while (n != null) {
        if (n.down != null) {
            q.add(n.down);
        }
        if (n.next == null) {
            n.next = q.poll();
        }
        n = n.next;
    }
}
```

I would also recommend to look at the deep-first approach which would flatten the structure above to `1 2 21 221 3 31 32 332 3332 3333 33 4`:

```
static void flatten(Node node) {
    Stack<Node> stack = new Stack<>();
    while (node != null) {
        if (node.down != null) {
            if (node.next != null) {
                stack.push(node.next);
            }
            node.next = node.down;
        } else if (node.next == null && !stack.empty()) {
            node.next = stack.pop();
        }
        node = node.next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sharing a O(n) solution. The idea is very simple.

- Get the right most pointer from the left side of the current node,
  and point it's  right pointer to parent's right.
- And then set the current node's left as it's right pointer.

Solution (Refer to inline comments):

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * public class TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode left;
 *     TreeNode right;
 *     TreeNode() {}
 *     TreeNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
 *     TreeNode(int val, TreeNode left, TreeNode right) {
 *         this.val = val;
 *         this.left = left;
 *         this.right = right;
 *     }
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    public void flatten(TreeNode root) {
        if (root == null) {
            return;
        }
        TreeNode newr = new TreeNode(-1);
        newr = root;
        dfs(root);
        root = newr;
    }
    
    TreeNode dfs(TreeNode node) {
        
        TreeNode left = null;
        if(node.left != null) {
           left = dfs(node.left);
        }
        
        TreeNode right = null;
        if(node.right != null) {
           right = dfs(node.right);
        }
         
        // Before this, refer to the comment in the return line
        if (left != null) {
            // Point the right pointer of the right most node, of the left
            // side of the parent, to the parent's right node.
            left.right = node.right;
            node.right = node.left;
        }

        // Do remember to clear the left node of the current node.
        node.left = null;
        
        // Try to return the rightmost node, so that when we 
        // reach the parent, and the if the "right" node returned here
        // happens to be at the left side of the parent, then we  can point 
        // it's right pointer to the parent's right node.

        return right != null ? right : left != null ? left : node; 
    }
}
```